# Controlling facet column number with visreg

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visreg

While I am enjoying using package `visreg` to visualize my regressions, there's one thing that I can't yet control: the number of columns when faceting. See the following factor-by-curve generalized additive regression for example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mgcv)
library(visreg)
data(airquality)
test <- gam(
    Ozone ~ s(Temp, by = Month),
    data = airquality %>% mutate(Month = as.factor(Month))
)
```

If I do

```
visreg(test, xvar = "Temp", by = "Month", gg = TRUE)
```

I get a 1-row, 5-column factor-by-curves.

[image]

Funnily enough, if I take the `gg = TRUE` out, it becomes 2-row. But whichever is the case I would like to be able to control the number of columns and rows when faceting. So far I have been unsuccessful, by either manipulating the ellipsis argument of `visreg` or by directly trying to manipulate the resulting `ggplot` object.

So for example, if I wanted to do `visreg` with `gg = TRUE` with 3-row, 2-column, what would be my best chance---or is there another package that is recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just modify the ggplot object and add `facet_wrap` in the usual way:

```
p <- visreg(test, xvar = "Temp", by = "Month", gg = TRUE)
p + facet_wrap(vars(Month), nrow = 3)
```

[image]

You don't actually need to create `p` first, this gives the same result:

```
visreg(test, xvar = "Temp", by = "Month", gg = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Month), nrow = 3)
```